# Returning an itterable object to Ajax from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

How can I iterate through the object sent back from the php script below in my jquery/ajax call?
I tried `result[0]` whiche gave me back `c`. That means that I'm being returned a string.What code should I write to be returned `company1` etc. ?

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;

CREATE TABLE company(
name VARCHAR(255),
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

INSERT INTO company(name) VALUES( 'company1'); 
INSERT INTO company(name) VALUES( 'company2');
INSERT INTO company(name) VALUES( 'company2');
```

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "manager-get-company.php",
    success: function (response) {
        //iterate through response here
        //console.log(response[0]; -> log Company1
        //console.log(response[1]; -> log Company2
    }
});
```

```
<?php

//manager-get-company.php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database_name = 'test';
 $con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database_name);

 //Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}

$sql= mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT name FROM company');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ajax add `dataType : "json",`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    url: "manager-get-company.php",
    success: function (response) {
        //iterate through response here
        if(!response.error){
          console.log(response[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

In php

```
$result = [];
 //Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  $result['error'] = "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
  $sql= mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT name FROM company');
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $result[] = $row['name'];
  }
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Edited : use `$result['error']` not `result['error']`

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I still get a 500 error code from running that

Comment: @VectorXY If your code returns value `c` as you said so my code should work fine for you.. Please copy/paste my code and try again

Comment: @VectorXY I changed `array_push` line to ` $result[]` check it

Comment: @VectorXY  Sorry `$result= array_push(` should be `array_push(..` directly without `$result =` anyway `$result[] = $row['name']` will work

Comment: yeah works fine now. I should look into arrays deeper. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're totally welcome @VectorXY .. Have a nice day :-)